# No-break spaces aren't displayed correctly — Mauvais affichage des espaces insécables

Tags: bug, characters

J'ai remarqué dans beaucoup de post seulement sur *french.se* que les espaces insécables ne s'affichent pas correctement pour moi. Je vois ceci :

> [image: Chrome Screenshot]

Cependant, cela n'affecte seulement que chrome et IE8 (sur Firefox, ils s'affichent comme il faut).

Voici la même phrase sur firefox :

> [image: Firefox Screenshot]

Je suis sur Windows XP, chrome version 36.0.1985.125, firefox (aurora) version 32.0a2.

Comment: See here: https://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/235/is-there-a-french-language-character-map. The font from XP lacks those characters.

Comment: Then how come firefox is not affected by that? If you say it is XP, then it should affect every browser, right?

Comment: Firefox probably uses its own fonts.

Comment: I see!... Thanks, I guess I'll just ignore these boxes for now `:P`.